# Mapeamento JPA List<Map..>

Tags: java, jpa

Estou com o seguinte problema e gostaria de alguma opinião para saber qual a melhor abordagem:

Vamos supor que tenha um sistema que gerencia uma escola e gostaria de dispor a opção para o administrador do sistema em que o mesmo pode cadastrar uma modalidade/aula que seja e vincular preços de acordo com os dias da semana disponíveis para essa aula.

Por exemplo:

- Aula de JPA está disponível SEGUNDA, QUARTA e SEXTA por 50 reais, ou
  TERÇA e QUINTA por 35 reais;
- Aula de JSF está disponível de SEGUNDA a SEXTA por 80 reais, ou
  TERÇA, QUARTA e QUINTA por 40 reais.

Ou seja, dar a opção para o administrador criar um preço de acordo com os dias da semana. Qual seria a melhor opção para mapeamento JPA?

Inicialmente criei um `Enum` com todos os dias da semana e pensei em criar algo como uma `List<Map<List<DiasDaSemana>, Double>> precos`, meio confuso certo?

Alguém tem alguma ideia de qual a melhor maneira de resolver isso, e caso esse seja um caminho aceitável como seria o tipo de mapeamento a ser realizado? Através de um `@ElementCollection`? Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

Comment: E se você encapsular em um novo objeto algo do tipo: List<PrecosDaSemana>, e em PrecosDaSemana ter uma variável de outro objeto que encapsula sua outra lista de dia da semana, ex: Map<PrecoSemanal, Double>, e por fim PrecoSemanal tem sua lista de DiasDaSemana. Daí você mapeia cada objeto normalmente sem muita confusão.

Comment: @Bruno, isto me parece mais uma questão de modelagem de banco de dados do que de JPA mesmo. É preciso definir primeiro como ficará o conjunto de tabelas que irão armazenar estas informações para depois pensarmos no mapeamento com JPA.

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria da seguinte maneira:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;

public class Curso {
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}

public class Preco {
    private int id;
    // já tem no Java, não tem porque criar outro enum
    private DayOfWeek diaDaSemana; 
    // nunca trabalhe com valores financeiros usando Double ou Float a perda de precisão pode te causar problemas, especialmente em relatários
    private BigDecimal preco;
    private Curso curso;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public DayOfWeek getDiaDaSemana() {
        return diaDaSemana;
    }
    public void setDiaDaSemana(DayOfWeek diaDaSemana) {
        this.diaDaSemana = diaDaSemana;
    }
    public BigDecimal getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }
    public void setPreco(BigDecimal preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }
    public Curso getCurso() {
        return curso;
    }
    public void setCurso(Curso curso) {
        this.curso = curso;
    } 
}
```

Pra acessar, use:

```
List<Preco> precos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tive a ideia de criar um mapa para as opções desse jeito:

`Map<String, Map<String,Double>> opções = new HashMap();`

Desse jeito você pode especificar os cursos no mapa externo e no mapa interno específicas o dia da semana e o respectivo preço.

Answer (score 0):

Como dito num comentário, esse problema é de modelagem de banco de dados. Depois de modelar o banco, você cria as entidades JPA (embora alguns tutoriais de JPA e outros ORMs sugiram o contrário...).

**(Opção 1)**

Nesse caso um jeito seria criar uma tabela chamada **PrecoPorDia** com colunas/atributos ID_CURSO, DIA_SEMANA, VALOR. Se DIA_SEMANA não for suficiente, você pode criar itens mais complexos nessa enum, como TerQui (terça e quinta), SegQuaSex (segunda, quarta e sexta) e DeSegASex (de segunda a sexta).

**(Opção 2)**

Mas tenho uma sugestão mais completa:

Crie dois conceitos separados: um é o **Curso** e o outro é, digamos, a **AplicacaoCurso** ou InstanciaCurso ou algo assim (o nome você pode aperfeiçoar).

A tabela/classe Curso conteria apenas os dados imutáveis do curso, como nome, categoria, conteúdo programático, pré-requisitos.

Já a tabela/classe AplicacaoCurso teria uma referência ao curso (ID_CURSO) e adicionaria dados específicos para aquela instância do curso: data de início e fim, número da sala, professor, dias da semana, preço. Veja por este lado: um mesmo curso pode ser ministrado por professores diferentes, em salas diferentes e pode ter preços diferentes dependendo do período (verão ou inverno, terça+quinta ou segunda+quarta, apenas sábados, etc.) e ainda assim ser o mesmo curso!

Dá pra parar por aqui ou, se necessário, podemos agora retomar a ideia inicial e criar o PrecoPorDia (ou PrecoPorPeriodo) que sugeri no começo. Nesse caso AplicacaoCurso não teria o preço diretamente, mas referenciaria um valor correspondente a uma das opções existentes, fazendo alguns joins.

Existem alguns detalhes que precisam ser aperfeiçoados. Ex.: PrecoPorPeriodo conterá a data de aplicação do curso? Se não contiver, como serão feitos os reajustes nos próximos anos? Se tiver, será que a tabela PrecoPorPeriodo não fica muito igual à tabela já existente AplicacaoCurso? Neste caso bastaria a AplicacaoCurso mesmo... Fica aí o problema para pensarmos :-)

Criando e dando nome aos conceitos separadamente desde o início, você não terá uma estrutura `List<Map<List<DiasDaSemana>, Double>> precos` e sim `List<AplicacaoCurso> cursos`. Depois você pode criar métodos de busca como **findByDiaDaSemana** utilizando SQL conforme precisar.

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria assim:

```java
class Courses{
    private Long id;
    private String title;

    ....

    private BigDecimal price_promotion;
    private BigDecimal price;

    ....

    public BigDecimal getPricePromotionSpecificDay(){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date d = new Date();

        c.setTime(d);

        if(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 4 || c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 3){
            return price_promotion;
        }

        return price;
    }
}
```

quando você for fazer a chamada, basta chamar este método.